# Mixin adding defaultImpl in Jackson does not work

Tags: kotlin, jackson, mixins, jackson-databind, jackson2

I want to use Jackson mixin to provide a default implementation for an abstract type:

```kotlin
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = Id.NAME,
    include = As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type",
    visible = true,
    defaultImpl = GenericRequest::class
)
@JsonMixin(Request::class)
class AlexaRequestMixin {
}

data class GenericRequest(
    val type: String, val requestId: String, val timestamp: OffsetDateTime
)
```

Base class that I want to alter with a mixin:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = Id.NAME,
    include = As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type",
    visible = true
)
@JsonSubTypes({@Type(
    value = InstallationError.class,
    name = "Alexa.DataStore.PackageManager.InstallationError"
), 
// ...
)})
public abstract class Request {
```

My `objectMapper`:

[image: object mapper]

However when I try to deserialize a class that is not present as subtype I get:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'Foo' as a subtype of 'com.amazon.ask.model.Request': known type ids = [...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it work I had to:

Make `GenericRequest` extend from the abstract `Request` class.

When an abstract class is from Java and inheriting data class is from Kotlin it causes lots of problems.

a) Data class cannot override same properties from abstract class https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6653/Kotlin-properties-do-not-override-Java-style-getters-and-setters

b) I had to change `include = As.PROPERTY` to `include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_ARRAY`

So I ended up with implementing `GenericRequest` extending `Request` in Java...